# Access mysql database in eclipse using java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, web-services, jdbc

I created a simple mysql database table using following query:

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
name varchar(20),
C_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
address  varchar(20),
email varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY(C_ID)
);
```

Now I want to insert values to this table. My client like this:

```
package com.orderdata.ws;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class OrderData {
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orderdata","root","chathura");
    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String insert = "INSERT INTO customer(name,C_ID,address,email)      VALUES (a,5,b,c)";
    stmt.executeUpdate(insert);

}

}
```

But this gives an exception "Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(a,5,b,c)' at line 1............"

How can I insert data using eclipse???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When inserting varchar text to MySQL tables, you need to surround it in single quotes like this:

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO customer(name,C_ID,address,email) VALUES ('a',5,'b','c');";
```

Answer (score 1):

Access databases need ";" at the end of sql command.

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO customer(name,C_ID,address,email) VALUES ('a',5,'b','c');";
```

Edit: And you need to put text data into query like this

```
VALUES ('a',5,'b','c')
```

You may need to "escape" ' (quote) characters. I dont know how to do this in java, maybe like this:

```
VALUES (\'a\',5,\'b\',\'c\')
```

Comment: Still have the same problem
"Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(a,5,b,c)' at line 1
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native M...